# plot meaningful graphs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot graphs to see how battery voltage is affected by output current. I have usage data of devices using the battery. and when output current is zero battery voltage should not drop. this is what i want to check. I have data of 10 dates on different time intervals. I want to plot one for each days showing the pattern. I am attaching a picture of just a sample data that looks similar to my actual data.
 
[image]

result so far
 
[image]

Comment: And what have you tried to plot till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#read data from pandas into a numpy array
#assume this is our dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':    [ 3,  29, 30],
                    'height': [94, 170,200]})

#reshape data
m = df.values
m = m[:,::-1].transpose()

#plot the graph
plt.scatter(m[0], m[1])
plt.plot(m[0], m[1], '-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: see the pic in edit , i have added the output of your code

Comment: Well if you could write down some values for us to work with, then that'd be great. I'm not going to manually type them in :p

Comment: Would you explain what is the benefit of the *data reshape* you offered by `m = m[:,::-1].transpose()` to catch meaningful plot via dataframe? OP showed the dataframe which contains `date`  column. So the first meaningful plot crossed to my mind is reaching *time-series* plot! Please see this [picture](https://i.imgur.com/79tu3iw.jpg)